# Можно ли выполнить валидацию вот такого элемента средствами Angular?

Tags: angular2

В общем, сделал элемент, который добавляет теги подобно SO:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2" for="search">Теги</label>
        <div id="tag-editor" class="col-sm-10 form-control">
          <span class="tag" *ngFor="let tag of selectedTags.values()">{{tag.name}}<a class="close"
              (click)="onRemove(tag)">&times;</a></span>
          <input id="tag-search" name="search" placeholder="Search" #searchTag (input)="doSearchTag(searchTag.value)"
            (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="search-results" class="col-sm-10 offset-md-2" *ngIf="searchResult&&searchResult.length>0">
          <div class="search-result unselectable" *ngFor="let tag of searchResult" (click)="onSelectTag(tag)">
            {{tag.name}} -> {{tag.description}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

При выборе из списка элемента он добавляется в коллекцию компонента, а затем слева рисуется span-прямоугольник с названием тега.

Собственно, вопрос:

Я могу как-то хитро на это повесить required и использовать переменную шаблона, что бы потом использовать в выражении например `[disabled]="!tags.valid"` ?

Comment: я заметил такую консистенцию что вы часто отвечаете на свой вопрос вопросом, почему бы вам сначала не попробовать, а только потом создать здесь вопрос? `Сначала более подробно опишите проблему, которую вы сформулировали в заголовке. Поясните, как вы столкнулись с проблемой и что препятствует её решению. `

Comment: @overthesanity я пробовал методом научного тыка прийти к желаемому результату, но что-то не получилось... Собственно, задался вопросом, а можно ли вообще на это повесить валидацию через шаблонную переменную. Потому что на обычные инпуты все без проблем вешается.